# Migrate lucene FST files from 5.1.0 to 8.9.0

Tags: lucene, fst

I have files with FST's created with lucene 5.1.0.

After upgrading to lucene 8.9.0 I get exception when I am trying to read FST from file:

```
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooOldException: Format version is not supported (resource org.apache.lucene.store.InputStreamDataInput@34ce8af7): 4 (needs to be between 6 and 7). This version of Lucene only supports indexes created with release 6.0 and later.
```

Is there any way to upgrade old FST files to new format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way.

Write all content from FST to text file:

```
public static <T> void writeToTextFile(FST<T> fst, Path filePath) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(filePath)) {
        BytesRefFSTEnum<T> fstEnum = new BytesRefFSTEnum<>(fst);
        while (fstEnum.next() != null) {
            BytesRefFSTEnum.InputOutput<T> inputOutput = fstEnum.current();
            writer.write(inputOutput.input.utf8ToString() + "\t" + inputOutput.output.toString() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Change lucene version to new and read content from file:

```
public static <T> FST<T> readFromTextFile(Path filePath, Outputs<T> outputs, Function<String, T> fromString) throws IOException {
    Builder<T> builder = new Builder<>(FST.INPUT_TYPE.BYTE1, outputs);
    IntsRefBuilder scratchInts = new IntsRefBuilder();

    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(filePath)) {
        String[] split = reader.readLine().split("\t");

        BytesRef scratchBytes = new BytesRef(split[0]);
        builder.add(Util.toIntsRef(scratchBytes, scratchInts), fromString.apply(split[1]));
    }

    return builder.finish();
}
```